# Test values from NSMutableArray and display to Tableview

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, tableview

I have an NSMutableArray;

```
array=(
 {
  names=a;
  score=2;
 },
 {
  names=b;
  score=5;
 },
 {
  names=c;
  score=20;
 }
)
```

First I want to test if the score is greater than 10, then display all the values in a tableview;

I'm having hard time how to access the array, I'm coming from a PHP's view point so I really don't have any clues

I'm getting a SIGABRT with

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I presume because I haven't digest the array or I'm passing the whole array content into the cell which might be choking and spitting it out.

Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 2):

Best is to rewrite your array to new one to avoid overhead of doing it in every cell.

You can do it for instance in `viewDidLoad` like that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (ArrayElement *arrayObject in self.array)
    {
        if ([[arrayObject score] intValue] > 10)
        {
            [self.filteredArray addObject:arrayObject];
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `self.filteredArray` in your `tableView` delegates.

Comment: Also for SIGABRT issue it should be like that `cell.textLabel.text = [[self.filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] score];` because you are currently assigning array element to string.